# AES Encryption Pad Block Corrupted

Tags: android, encryption

I keep searching for answers to this question but none that I could find give me back actual corrected code that I can use, unless I am seriously missing something. I have a simple program that I am testing encryption and decryption. I have the user input and then a encrypt and decrypt button that onClick should display the encrypted and then decrypted data but I keep getting this error:

```
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:739)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at io.test.encryption.app.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:61)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at io.test.encryption.app.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:34)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at io.test.encryption.app.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
1105-1105/io.test.encryption.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

String seedValue = "This is a Secret";
String encrypted, decrypted;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    final TextView textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    final String input = inputText.getText().toString();



    Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                encrypted = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(seedValue, input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textView1.setText(encrypted);

        }

         });
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                decrypted = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(seedValue, encrypted);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final TextView textView2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView2.setText(decrypted);
                        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

And here is my Simple Crypto Class

```
public class SimpleCrypto {

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    final SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}

}
```

Comment: Debug, in particular log the arguments of all `SimpleCrypto` methods in both `onClick` handlers. Add you are calling `inputText.getText().toString();` in the `onCreate`, isn't it empty at that time?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use plain byte[] to generate your key, using String can generate values not mapped by encoding used.

You can look at working example [here](https://github.com/MoraisIgor/AndroidUtility/blob/master/code/src/com/hollowsoft/library/utility/crypto/SymmetricCrypto.java).

Hope its helps.

Comment: to be honest I am new to android and encryption and this basic example is as far as I have gotten. I am not sure how to use the code you gave me in my application. I cannot just replace the entire SimpleCrypto class as that is what my boss wants me to use. I thought there would be a line or two that I have to change or add but your code seems completely different?